# Erlang enif_alloc_resource always segmentation fault

Tags: c, erlang

I write a `c nif` code and when i call the function `find_next`, erlang vm exits with segmentation fault in line `struct Node *n = (struct Node*) enif_alloc_resource(MEM_RESOURCE, sizeof(Node));`.

C code:

```
struct Node {
    int n;
    int* elems;
    int c;
} Node;


static ErlNifResourceType *MEM_RESOURCE;

static ERL_NIF_TERM find_next_nif(ErlNifEnv* env, int argc, const ERL_NIF_TERM argv[])
{
    int len;
    const ERL_NIF_TERM *args;
    if (!enif_get_tuple(env, argv[0], &len, &args))
        return enif_make_badarg(env);

    struct Node *n = (struct Node*) enif_alloc_resource(MEM_RESOURCE, sizeof(Node));

    return enif_make_int(env, 0);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you called enif_open_resource_type() somewhere?

Comment: Oh i forgot it. Tnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you call enif_open_resource_type() when you load your NIF.

In your NIF declaration, the third argument is nif_load in this example:

```
ERL_NIF_INIT(your_nif, nif_funcs, nif_load, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

In your load function, along with anything else you do, you should call enif_open_resource_type(), something like this:

```
static int nif_load(ErlNifEnv * env, void ** priv_data, ERL_NIF_TERM load_info) {
```

...

```
    MEM_RESOURCE = enif_open_resource_type(
            env, NULL, "your_nif", NULL,
            ERL_NIF_RT_CREATE, NULL);
```